# What exactly happened? This looks like an attack

Tags: security, logout, teamviewer

I was watching a movie and suddenly I was logged out. When I logged back in, Team Viewer was started immediately, although it's not on startup programs.

Quickly I opened the terminal and gave the command `sudo last`, but it was not showing anything suspicious. Last but not least, no updates were made​​.

Any idea?

Comment: This site is not fit for urgent matters. It is also very specific to your situation probably. For a forensic analysis on your system consult an expert with access to the machine. A Q&A site is not the right place, really. I'm editing your question as per [How do we deal with “urgent!” questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5849/88802)

Comment: If you sincerely feel that your machine has been compromised, take it off-line and rebuild it from scratch. There is not much more we can help you with here as we don't perform forensics.

Comment: Also, what do you expect for an answer? Do you want to know whether this is suspicious or not? What happened exactly? How to trace the attacker? etc. A statement about what you saw and then "Any idea?" does not really show your actual question.

Comment: Tried `dmesg | tail` or just `dmesg`?

Answer (score 5):

Your system was likely not attacked. Teamviewer starts with the system by default (annoying I know, but true anyway) in the latest version I've tried.

The solution is to check both startup programs, and the following locations:

```
/home/rolandixor/.config/autostart
/usr/share/autostart
```

for an entry for Teamviewer, and if it exists, to remove it.

You were likely logged out due to a Xserver crash (this occasionally happens when watching videos or playing games, especially on proprietary drivers in my experience). Make sure that you apply any updates you may have missed.

Comment: well, thanks for your answer, but stil....i just checked in /home/my-username/.config/autostart and there are only 2 programs (dropbox.desktop and remina-applet.desktop)

Comment: in /usr/share/...autostart folder does not exist

Comment: I have the system up to date

Comment: Run `locate autostart` and look for a Teamviewer.desktop file in any of the folders you find.